# Why does replacing "(null x)" with "(null (cdr x))" make this code work?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm a newbie in LISP. I'm trying to write a bubble sort function in LISP.

This is what I've done so far.

```
(defun mysort (x)
  (if (null  x) x
    (if (< (car x) (cadr x))
     (cons (car x) (mysort (cdr l)))
     (cons (cadr x) (mysort (cons (car x) (cddr x)))))))
```

I'm getting an error

```
NIL is not a real number
```

When I modified the code like (after referring several codes)-

```
(defun mysort (x)
  (if (null  (cdr x)) x
   (if (< (car x) (cadr x))
    (cons (car x) (mysort (cdr l)))
    (cons (cadr x) (mysort (cons (car x) (cddr x)))))))
```

Now it works fine.

Why does replacing
    (if (null  x) x...)
with
    (if (null  (cdr x)) x...)
make a difference?

Also, I'm calling mysort from another function to run it (length x) number of times. Is it possible to achieve complete sorting in a single recursive loop, only using the basic functions?

Comment: What is `(cdr x)` in the working/failing cases? How does this relate to the `x` that is used/returned? Imagine when x is `'(a)`/`(cons 'a nil)` vs `'()`/`nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a comparison you need at least two elements so checking if `x` is `NIL` is not enough.

Checking if `(cdr x)` is `NIL` is a nice way to check that the list length is at least two because `NIL` is special and even if it's not a cons cell it's guaranteed that `(cdr NIL)` is `NIL`.

The error you were getting is because `NIL` is not a number thus you cannot compare with `<` a number with it and this was happening when executing `(< (car x) (cadr x))` when `x` was a list with a single element.

About sorting in a single recursive call you could use this definition of sorting:

- an empty list is sorted
- a non-empty list is sorted if the first element is the minimum of the list and the rest of the list is sorted.

This leads to

```
(defun mysort (x)
  (if x
      (let ((minimum (reduce #'min x)))
        (cons minimum
              (mysort (remove minimum x :count 1))))))
```

That, by the way, is a **very** inefficient way to do the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see if the first element is smaller than the second element, then the list needs to have at least two elements.

If there is only one element, `CADR` returns `NIL`. This is not a number.

```
CL-USER 18 > (cadr '(1))
NIL
```

Your Lisp system should not only tell you the error, but also the function where it occurred. Here: the function `<`.

Using `(null (cdr list))` is a good way to test if there is a second element. A typical error would be to call `LENGTH`, which is inefficient.